# olAppointmentItem FROM property

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am attempting to send an invite using a shared calendar that I have access to.

It keeps defaulting to my primary ID calendar.

This is what I have so far.

```
Dim O As Outlook.Application
Set O = New Outlook.Application
Dim OAPT As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Set OAPT = O.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
OAPT.MeetingStatus = olMeeting

With OAPT
    ans = MsgBox("You are about to send an Invite for #: " & Sheets("NIN").Range("D19"), vbYesNo)
    If ans = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    .Subject = "Invite - " ' & Worksheets("NIN").Range("D12") & " - " & Worksheets("Paste").Range("A21") & " - "
    'StartTime = Sheets("Bridges").Range("N2").Value
    '.Start = StartTime
    .Duration = 30
    .Recipients.Add ("test@test.com;")

    If InStr(1, ([NIN!D19].Value), "SMB") > 0 Then
        .Location = Worksheets("NIN").Range("D20")
        .Body = Worksheets("Bridges").Range("M2").Value
        Worksheets("Bridges").Range("M1").Copy
        .GetInspector.WordEditor.Windows(1).Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPASTERTF

    Else:
        .Location = Worksheets("Paste").Range("B21")
        .Body = Worksheets("Bridges").Range("N1").Value
    End If

    .Display

End With
```

I tried `SendUsingAccount` and that did not work either, nor did `GetSharedDefaultFolder`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `CreateItem` method of the `Application` class:

```
Set OAPT = O.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
```

Go to the shared calendar and add a new item there by using the [Items.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.add) method:

```
Dim myItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem
' 
Set myItem = yourSharedCalendar.Items.Add
```

The [How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/) article explains all possible ways of creating outlook appointment items.

Comment: Hi Eugene, any chance you might be able to provide an example of how I might be able to config my code to get the result I need? Not very knowledgable in VBA so any help would be appreciated. Spacibo in advance

Comment: You just need to get a shared folder by using the `GetSharedDefaultFolder` method and then use the `Items.Add` method.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but not sure how to implement it into my code. Thats the problem. Any chance you can modify the code I posted to include it, or at least a snippet of it so I can copy / paste it?

Comment: `Set OAPT = O.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar).Items.Add`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this before as well with no success:

```
enter code here

Dim myoutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim myRecipients As Outlook.Recipient
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim oCalendar As Object
Dim oSession As Object
Dim OAPT As Object
Const olAppointmentItem = 1
Const olMeeting = 1


Set myRecipient = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").CreateRecipient("test@gmail.com")
Set OAPT = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
Outlook.Application.Session.Logon
Set OAPT = Outlook.Application.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar).Items.Add

With OAPT
```

Comment: There is no need to create an appointment using the `CreateAppointment` method in the code.

Comment: The code will not be working. Where did you create a new Outlook `Application` instance?